# Understanding Nested For Loop To Print Asterisk Pattern

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, nested

Can someone explain how this Nested For Loop prints the Asterisk pattern. I don't understand how the actual loop works and prints the pattern, I know that cout prints the astrix('s) but how does it know to print 1 astrix, then 2, then 3.. etc

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int a, cols, rows;
cout << " Please enter a number: ";
cin >> a;

for (cols = 1; cols < a + 1; cols++) {
    for (rows = 0; rows < cols; rows++)
        cout << "*";
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is pch.h ?

Comment: My advice is to use your debugger. Set a breakpoint at the cout and see what is printed each time. Inspect the variables.

Comment: I was told pch.h needs to be included for visual studio to work

Comment: @itsTed You were told wrong.

Comment: ***what is pch.h*** That is for precompiled headers. For a small program like this (or any program that does not have hundreds of external includes) it is best to turn off precompiled headers when creating the project. Although you can also turn it off in the project settings. Why I say its best is it actually does not help (could make compiling longer not shorter) for small programs that don't use many external headers.

Comment: Ted, precompiled headers is the default for Visual Studio, so unless you know what it is and how to turn it off It must be included. Note: It MUST be the first non-comment in the source file or much strangeness can occur. Everything above it WILL be ignored. Don't put it in a header file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you are accepting the user input for the size of the pattern. Now suppose the input or the value of a is 3.

Now when the first loop executes, it starts like this
for(cols=1; cols<4; cols++)
Now when the execution goes to the nested loop, the loop looks like this
for(rows=0; rows<1; rows++)

In the nested loop the condition gets satisfied as because 0 is less than 1 so it prints the first asterisk  "*" and the inner loop stops, and the execution moves further and cout << endl moves to a newline i.e. it inserts a newline character.

For the 2nd iteration of the outer loop, the value of cols becomes 2 and after that it again enters the inner or the nested loop. Here the inner loop looks like this :- for(rows=0; rows<2; rows++)
Now 0 is less than 2 so the loop executes and prints an asterisk "*" and the inner loop's execution continues and again the value of rows gets incremented to 1. Since 1 is also less than 2, so it again prints an asterisk, and the execution of the inner loop stops, leaving two asterisks in the console, i.e. "**".

So you have a pattern like this

> ```
> *
> **
> ```

And the above mentioned process continues and it again prints 3 sets of asterisk and like this it goes on and gets terminated as soon as the outer loop's condition becomes false.

Answer (score 2):

> "which for statement does it look at first"

You have a wrong idea of how the computer runs such a program - it's not "looking at" your code and figuring out what you want to do, it simply goes line by line.

You can watch this happen step by step by using a debugger. Place a breakpoint on the `cin >> a;` line and keep stepping forward - you will see exactly what the program does and you can look at all the variables at any time. (This is best done in a **debug build** of your code.)

Comment: it simply goes line by line is quite an oversimplification. It that would be true, writing an interpreter would be trivial

Comment: @user463035818 I'm very much open to an alternative phrasing that would be less oversimplified but still gets the point across in this context.

Comment: i am thinking... maybe in the scope of this question its just fine

Answer (score 0):

to prtint reverse triangle, you can use this way

```
    for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    for (let j = num -1 ; j > i; j--) {
      if(j == num-1 ){
        spacein += ""  
      } else {
        spacein += "  "
      }
    }
    if(i == num-1) {

    } else {
      console.log(space + "*" + spacein + "*")
    }

    space += " "
    spacein = ""
  }
```